# How can i resolve the "This SQLTransaction has completed; it is no longer available? (linq/EF)

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, transactions, entity-framework-core

I have a database first, .net core 2.1 Entity Framework razor page application. It is a homework problem to create a banking application but I do not know why this small part does not work. When i break up the code into separate methods my transaction does not complete or even roll back correctly. The error i get is "This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable." When i pull the code out of separate methods and into the "TransferCheckingToSaving", it works correctly.

I have tried to pass the transaction variable as an input to each of the sub-methods, and those methods do not error out. When it gets down to the commit int the "TransferCheckingToSaving", it throws the error.

```cs
public bool TransferCheckingToSaving(long checkingAccountNum, long savingAccountNum, decimal amount, decimal transactionFee)
{
    bool ret = false;

    using (var contextTransaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            bool updateSavingSuccess = UpdateSavingBalanceTR(savingAccountNum, amount, contextTransaction);
            if (updateSavingSuccess != true)
                throw new Exception("The saving account balance did not update successfully while transferring from checking to saving");
            bool updateCheckingSuccess = UpdateCheckingBalanceTR(checkingAccountNum, -1 * amount, contextTransaction);
            if (updateCheckingSuccess != true)
                throw new Exception("The checking account balance did not update successfully while transferring from checking to saving");
            bool addToTransHistSuccess = AddToTransactionHistory(checkingAccountNum, savingAccountNum, amount, 100, 0, contextTransaction);
            if (addToTransHistSuccess != true)
                throw new Exception("Failed to update the transaction history while transferring from checking to saving");
            else
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
                contextTransaction.Commit();
                ret = true;
                CacheAbstraction cabs = new CacheAbstraction();
                cabs.Remove(CacheNameFacade.TRCACHENAME + ":" + checkingAccountNum); 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            contextTransaction.Rollback();
            throw ex;
        }

    }
    return ret;
}
```

```cs
private bool UpdateCheckingBalanceTR(long checkingAccountNum, decimal amount, IDbContextTransaction transaction)
{
    bool ret = false;

    try
    {
        using (transaction)
        {
            CheckingAccounts checkingAcct = (from c in _context.CheckingAccounts where c.CheckingAccountNumber == checkingAccountNum select c).FirstOrDefault<CheckingAccounts>();
            checkingAcct.Balance += (decimal)amount;
            if (checkingAcct.Balance < 0)
                throw new Exception("The checking balance of " + (checkingAcct.Balance -= amount).ToString() + " is too low to complete this transaction");
            _context.SaveChanges();
            ret = true;
            return ret;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    //return ret;
}
```

```cs
private bool UpdateSavingBalanceTR(long savingAccountNum, decimal amount, IDbContextTransaction transaction)
{
    bool ret = false;
    try
    {
        using (transaction)
        {
            SavingAccounts savingAcct = (from s in _context.SavingAccounts where s.SavingAccountNumber == savingAccountNum select s).FirstOrDefault<SavingAccounts>();
            savingAcct.Balance += (decimal)amount;
            if (savingAcct.Balance < 0)
                throw new Exception("The checking balance of " + (savingAcct.Balance -= amount).ToString() + " is too low to complete this transaction");
            _context.SaveChanges();
            ret = true;
            return ret;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

```cs
private bool AddToTransactionHistory(long checkingAccountNum, long savingAccountNum, decimal amount, int transTypeId, decimal transFee, IDbContextTransaction transaction)
{
    bool ret = false;
    try
    {
        using (transaction)
        {
            TransactionHistories transHist = new TransactionHistories
            {
                CheckingAccountNumber = checkingAccountNum,
                SavingAccountNumber = savingAccountNum,
                Amount = amount,
                TransactionFee = transFee,
                TransactionTypeId = (long)transTypeId,
            };
            _context.TransactionHistories.Add(transHist);
            CacheAbstraction cabs = new CacheAbstraction();
            cabs.Remove(CacheNameFacade.TRCACHENAME + ":" + checkingAccountNum); //the checking account is the same for each unique user
            _context.SaveChanges();
            ret = true;
            return ret;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I expect the transaction to complete successfully but it throws the error "This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable." Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: You don't need to pass the transaction to the helper methods at all; you should only call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` *once* in the life of the transaction.

Comment: Really? That would do it I guess. We moved from writing sql to Entity Framework in my class recently so I'm not totally used to it yet. I'll give this a try when I get home from work. Thanks.

Comment: Note that Mark Benningfield's solution is correct. It appears that i cannot mark this as solved. Possibly since i am new?